# Pandas cumsum on groupby not behaving as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'prob':np.random.uniform(0,1,size), 'target':np.random.randint(0,2, size=size), 
              'pred':np.random.randint(0,2, size=size)})
```

That I want to compute `cumsum` of a `groupby` of a `qcut`:

```
df['box'] = pd.qcut(df['prob'], 10)
```

My expectation would be to calculate the cumulative function for each group, in order, but instead is calculating a sum for each element:

```
df['target_1'] = 1- df['target']
ch_curve = df.groupby('box').target.cumsum()/float(df.target.sum())
nch_curve = df.groupby('box').target_1.cumsum()/float(df.target_1.sum())
```

with the answer

```
0     0.000000
1     0.018182
2     0.018182
3     0.018182
4     0.000000
5     0.018182
6     0.018182
7     0.018182
8     0.036364
9     0.018182
10    0.000000
11    0.018182
12    0.018182
13    0.036364
14    0.000000
15    0.036364
16    0.036364
17    0.036364
18    0.054545
19    0.000000
20    0.000000
21    0.018182
22    0.018182
23    0.05454
```

instead of

```
'(0.0, 0.1)'    0.04
'(0.1, 0.2)'    0.12 #(0.08 + previous 0.04 )
'(0.2, 0.3)'    0.17 #(0.05 + previous 0.12 )
```

Comment: What is the result you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Cut a dataframe into 10 boxes by value and do the cumulative sum of the values of the elements of the group. Sum the values of the first group and divide by the count of that class in the entire dataframe.

Comment: A cumulative sum means 1 element for each element in the group. Sounds like you want 1 element for each group?

Comment: As the example above, I would like to get the group `(0.0, 0.1)`, sum all values of target for this group and divide by the total number of elements of target value equal to 1.

Comment: I would love to see what kind of Google searches will find this question.

Comment: Indeed. Didn't think about that.

Comment: Is this what you are talking about? `(df.groupby('box').target.sum() / df.target.sum()).cumsum()`

Comment: Yes, exactly. If you could please explain why this is way on an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to calculate the percentage for each group and **then** take the cumsum.

In your original code `df.groupby('box').target.cumsum()` will take the `cumsum` of each group - so you will have one element for each of the elements in the grouped DataFrame. Then the division will be broadcast across all of these elements.

Instead you want to get one summary statistic for each group and then take the `cumsum` across these statistics.

```
ch_curve = (df.groupby('box').target.sum() / df.target.sum()).cumsum()
nch_curve = (df.groupby('box').target_1.sum() / df.target_1.sum()).cumsum()
```

Comment: Yeah, agree. How could I edit the question to clarify this?

Comment: In this case expressing your intent in words or posting an explicit DataFrame with the desired result would help.